# Fixed point generalisation

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

If a continuous function  defined on an open interval in $R$ and the range is a proper subset of domain, then there exists a fixed point. Is this statement true? How about making domain and range compact and either of domain or range contains the other?

Answer (score 1):

Try the function $f(x) = x/2$ on $(0,1)$.

It's true for a function mapping a compact interval into itself by the [Brouwer fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: I am sorry, by proper subset I meant something like (0.1    0.9) I mean closure of range being subset of domain)

Comment: If so, there is a compact subinterval of the domain that contains the closure of the range, and you can use the Brouwer fixed point theorem.